# Controlling someone else's window screen

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a webpage where an admin can login as well as a random user.  I want the admin to be able to hit an exit button which will bring the user to a different screen.  In other words, using PHP I can show the exit button only when it's an admin logging in, but how do I modify my code so that pressing exit bring the user to a post-activity screen.

Part of the current code below:

```
    //exit is currently controlled on the user's screen - i want to modify that
    //only the admin should control this
    $("#exit").click(function(){
        $("#MainScreen").hide();
        $("#PostScreen").show();
    });
```

Comment: you could set a column in your db with a bool, set to true when user connect, and check on page loading if this value is true, if not redirect and kill session

Comment: I hadn't thought of using the database for that, but you're right.  When the admin clicks on exit I could modify a boolean indicator in the db.  I'd have to keep checking this value and if I see it switched then switch the user to the post screen. That's an interesting idea.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings: You want the admin be able to configure on which page a user gets redirected after he logs in?

`if(exitIsTrue) then (afterLogin.Response.Redirect("pageB") else ..."pageA")` ?

Comment: No, I have a chat that an admin is having with a user (they are both logged in), but I want the admin to be able to exit it (not the user), but when the admin exits the chat, I want it to cause the user to enter a new screen with some post-chat questions  (part of an experimental setup so I do not want the user to be able to exit on his/her own).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is possible... sort of, with a little creativity. In example, if the client side is using websockets or polling, it can constantly be checking for it's `state`. When you as the admin want the client pushed somewhere else, you push that information to the client (through websockets or polling) and then javascript will fire based on that action.

In example you can send the browser to a different URL based on the result of the poll.

The following code checks for a location URL every 200ms from the server

```
$(function() {
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $.get("/poll.php", function(data) {
            if (data.url !== "") {
                window.location.href = data.url;
            }
        }, "json");
    }, 200);
});
```

If you are willing to leave behind some older browsers, the same can be accomplished with less bandwidth using websockets.

You will never be able to do something like: `I do not want the user to be able to exit on his/her own`. You will never be able to prevent a user from closing their browser.

---

From a UX standpoint, would it be easier to just provide a link to the post-chat questions? Do you really need to force the user to go there?